# hadoop cluster configuration - nodes on dfsnodelist show up as localhost

Tags: hadoop

I'm using a setup of 2 VM's with hadoop 1.0.3. One Machine is configured as master, one as slave. Additional to the master services a set of slave services is running on the master node too.

The Machines are configured to have one external IP towards the company network (10.x.x.x) and an internal one where the services bind (172.16.x.x).

But on the site where you can investigate the nodes (masternode) 10.x.x.x:50070/dfsnodelist.jsp the names of the nodes are showing up as `localhost` and not as the hostname or the ip of the machine. Also the links are set to `localhost::50075/browseDirectory.jsp...`. I would expect to get the hostname or the configured IP's of the hosts (172.16.x.x)

Do you know where the configuration issue could be? Might be an explanation for all the other hiccups I'm having.

Comment: looks like dns doesn't function properly. dns should be able to reverse lookup by ip.

Comment: I have no DNS there for the internal "network" i have just assigned the IP`s to the adapters manually.

Or maybe i have screwed up my /etc/hosts configuration

master is mapped to 172.16.x.x, localhost is mapped to 127.0.0.1. In a other solution there was an additional mapping of master to 127.0.0.1, but apparently that coused problems for me and i removed that. (P.s.: I'm bad at configuring networking related stuff, I'm just a programmer and I have my strengths there)

Comment: Got the "inspiration" from this entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699753/hadoop-hdfs-cannot-connect-to-port-on-master/8705584#comment16919091_8705584

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

@octo was right, the dns didn't work properly. So i edited the `/etc/hosts` file to resolve the hostname of each machine to the IP towards the internal network

On master:

```
172.16.XX.XM      master master-hostname
172.16.XX.XS      slave
```

On slave:

```
172.16.XX.XM      master
172.16.XX.XS      slave slave-hostname
```